# Algorithm to find all possible binary combinations with a condition

Tags: c#, algorithm

Here is one is for you math brains out there.  I have a matrix, actually its half a matrix, cut diagonally. Each element of the matrix can be a **1** or a **0**.   I need to find all the possible combinations of **1**s and **0**s for any matrix of width **N**.

This is easy enough, you can get the number of elements on this matrix given width **N** with [image: formula] for this example where **N=7** this would give us **28** or the number of elements. Then you can get the combinations with [image: formula].

So the formula would be  [image: formula] to get all the possible combinations.

[image: empty]

Now here is where it gets tricky.  There is one condition that must hold true for each result.  The sum of the each set of elements on the matrix (shown below with each row represented) must be less than 4 for the first set (the one on the first row), less than 3 for all the other sets (these are constants regardless of the N value).

[image]

Here are what the sets for this example (**N=7**) look like.  If you notice each row is represented.  So for the first set if the combination is **0 1 0 1 0 1 0** this would be valid as its sum is < 4 (since its the first row).  For the second set if the combination is **1 0 0 0 0 1 0** it is valid as it needs to be < 3.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I need to do this for huge matrices so brute forcing all possible permutations to find the ones that fall under this condition would be unfeasable.  I need to find some sort of algorithm I can use to generate the valid matrices bottom up rather than top down. Maybe doing separate operations that can be composed later to yield a total set of results.

Any and all ideas are welcome.

Comment: Your condition doesn't seem clear enough. Could you elaborate more or give clear example?

Comment: Do you mean `N+1` instead of `N1` in the term for the number of elements in the matrix?

Comment: What do you mean by huge matrices? Can you tell limit of `n`?

Comment: And according to your design here, there is no way the 4 corner elements would fall in any category. Am I correct?

Comment: @Codor, correct N+1, the + got lost on the api used to render the formulas.  Fixed it.

Comment: @vish4071 N could go into the hundreds.  You found a bug on my explanation, the first two rows do get considered, but they don't make an L

Comment: @Mbo added more examples.

Comment: Sounds a little bit like linear programming to me, but without searching the optimal solution. So you have your set of conditions, but instead of maximizing or minimizing it, you just take every possible solution.

Comment: For me it looks like there are so many solutions, that even if you would have a algorithm, then just enumerating all solutions for large matrix would take so much time.

Comment: @Piters That is exactly what I'm looking for, a way to just take the solutions.

Comment: @JustAnotherCurious Indeed, but then it can be ran on a cluster and It will rain solutions piecemeal.  Which is where I wanna get to.

Comment: Am I the only one here that is unsure about the conditions? Are there only conditions on the rows, or are the conditions defined on the L-shaped lines you drew in the picture?

Comment: @MarceloMason Take a solver and adapt your objective function in an appropriate way. I suppose the conditions on the LP are clear, aren't they?

Answer (score 2):

A simple algorithm generating each solution recursively :

```
global File //A file where you will store your data
global N    //Your matrix size

//matrix contains the matrix we build (int[][])
//set contains the number of 1 we can use on a set (int[])
//c is the column number (int)
//r is the row number (int)
function f ( matrix, set, c, r ) :
  if ( c == N ):
    r = r + 1
    c = r

  if ( r == N ):
    write ( matrix in File )
    // Implement your own way of storing the matrix

  if ( set[r] > 0 AND (c+2 < N AND set[c+2] > 0) ):
    matrix[c][r] = 1
    set[c]--
    set[r]--
    f ( matrix, set, c+1, r )

  matrix[c][r] = 0
  f ( matrix, set, c+1, r)
end

//Calling our function with N = 5
N = 5
f([[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],...], [3,2,2,2,2], 0, 0)
```

You can store each matrix in something else than a file but keep an eye on your memory consumption.

Comment: I like this idea. I haven't checked your pseudo-code, but the idea behind it lets you systematically generate all possible solutions, by 'allocating' `1`s from two 'budgets': only if both budgets (here: `set`) have a `1` available can you allocate it in the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic idea to get started; it's too large for a comment, though, but not a complete answer.

The idea is to start with a maximally 'filled' matrix rather than an empty one and then filling it.

### Basic striping away procedure

Start with a matrix filled with all rows filled to their maximum number of `1`s, that is row 0 has 4 `1`s and the other rows each have 3 `1`s. Then, start checking the conditions. Condition 0 (row 0) is automatically satisfied. For the rest of the conditions, either they are satisfied, or there are too many `1`s in its condition set: take away `1`s until the condition is satisfied. Do this for all conditions.

### Generating all 'simpler' ones

Doing this, you end up with a matrix that satisfies all conditions. Now, you can change any `1` to a `0` and the matrix will still satisfy all the conditions. So, once you have a 'maximal' solution, you can generate all sub-solutions of it trivially.